# C# LiveCharts2 Update/Refresh View after modify value in PieCharts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I would like to update the view after modifying an element in the list. Currently, when I modify an item in my list, the series updates correctly, but not the view, or only partially. I should mention that the property being modified is the color, and if resize my window, the view updates correctly.

My Object :

```
`public class cDay : ObservableObject
 {
    public cDay()
    {
        byte[] abyColors = cColorConverter.HexToBytes("#A5A5A5");
        oColor = new SolidColorPaint(new SKColor(abyColors[0], abyColors[1], abyColors[2]));
    }
    private SolidColorPaint color;
    public SolidColorPaint oColor 
    {
        get => color;
        set
        {
            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private double value;
    public double Value
    {
        get => value;
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string label;
    public string Label
    {
        get => label;
        set
        {
            label = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}`
```

My ViewModel :

```
`internal class ViewModel : ObservableObject
 {
  public ViewModel()
  {
    InitColor();

    data = GetData();

    InitSeries();
  }

private static SolidColorPaint oColorRed;
private static SolidColorPaint oColorGreen;
private static SolidColorPaint oColorDefault;
private static SolidColorPaint oColorBlack;
private ObservableCollection<cDay> data;
private ISeries[] _Series;
public ISeries[] Series
{
    get
    {
        return _Series;
    }
    set
    {
        _Series = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<cDay> GetData()
{
    ObservableCollection<cDay> data = new ObservableCollection<cDay>()
    {
        new cDay() {Label = "J1", Value = 5 },
        new cDay() {Label = "J2", Value = 5 },
        new cDay() {Label = "J3", Value = 5 },
        new cDay() {Label = "J4", Value = 5 },
        new cDay() {Label = "J5", Value = 5 },
        new cDay() {Label = "J6", Value = 5 }
    };
    return data;
}
private void InitColor()
{
    string sHexColorRed = "#FF0000";
    string sHexColorBlack = "#000000";
    string sHexColorGreen = "#2AFF00";
    string sHexColorDefault = "#A5A5A5";
    byte[] abyColors = cColorConverter.HexToBytes(sHexColorRed);
    oColorRed = new SolidColorPaint(new SKColor(abyColors[0], abyColors[1], abyColors[2]));
    abyColors = cColorConverter.HexToBytes(sHexColorDefault);
    oColorDefault = new SolidColorPaint(new SKColor(abyColors[0], abyColors[1], abyColors[2]));
    abyColors = cColorConverter.HexToBytes(sHexColorGreen);
    oColorGreen = new SolidColorPaint(new SKColor(abyColors[0], abyColors[1], abyColors[2]));
    abyColors = cColorConverter.HexToBytes(sHexColorBlack);
    oColorBlack = new SolidColorPaint(new SKColor(abyColors[0], abyColors[1], abyColors[2]));
}

private void InitSeries()
{
    Series = null;
    var seriesCollection = data.AsPieSeries(
       (city, series) =>
       {
           series.Name = city.Label;
           series.InnerRadius = 60;
           series.Stroke = oColorBlack;
           series.Fill = city.oColor;
           series.Mapping = (cityMapper, point) =>
           {
               point.Coordinate = new Coordinate(point.Index, cityMapper.Value);

           };
           series.DataPointerDown += Series_DataPointerDown;
       });

    Series = seriesCollection.ToArray();
}

private void Series_DataPointerDown(IChartView chart, IEnumerable<ChartPoint<cDay, 
    DoughnutGeometry, LabelGeometry>> points)
{
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        string sOldName = point.Model?.Label;
        UpdateSerie(sOldName);
    }
}

private void UpdateSerie(string sName)
{
    foreach (cDay item in data)
    {
        if (item.Label == sName)
        {
            SKColor color = item.oColor.Color;
            if (color.ToString().ToUpper() == "#FFFF0000") // Rouge
            {
                item.oColor = oColorGreen;
            }
            else if (color.ToString().ToUpper() == "#FF2AFF00") //Vert
            {
                item.oColor = oColorDefault;
            }
            else if (color.ToString().ToUpper() == "#FFA5A5A5") // blanc default
            {
                item.oColor = oColorRed;
            }
        }
    }

    InitSeries();
}

}`
```

My View

`

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding Series,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  EasingFunction="{x:Null}"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Background="AliceBlue">

    </Grid>

 </Grid>`
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the following: you are binding your PieChart's series with an Array of ISeries, instead of a SeriesCollection (proper of LiveCharts package).

So, to make your code working you must change this:

```
private ISeries[] _Series;
    public ISeries[] Series
    {
        get
        {
            return _Series;
        }
        set
        {
            _Series = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Into this:

```
private SeriesCollection _Series;
    public SeriesCollection Series
    {
        get
        {
            return _Series;
        }
        set
        {
            _Series = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

You could find all info you need about SeriesCollection [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/583/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-using-the-livecharts-library-in-winforms-c-sharp) (pay attention to point 3 of this tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, but the use of SerieCollection is not
possible with LiveCharts2.

In the "adu" function, I have modified the parameters to include an IChartView and the data points of the graph. This information is transmitted through the DataPointerDown event.

I also modify the source object.
And use event:

```
series.DataPointerDown += Series_DataPointerDown
```

My new code :

```
private void Series_DataPointerDown(IChartView iChart, IEnumerable<ChartPoint<cDay, DoughnutGeometry, LabelGeometry>> loPoints)
{
    foreach (var point in loPoints)
    {
        if (point.Context.DataSource is cDay oDay)
        {
            if (oDay.m_bIsWeekDay)
            {
                SolidColorPaint oSolidColor = (SolidColorPaint)point.Visual.Fill;

                string sColor = oDay.m_sColor;
                if (sColor.ToUpper() == "#FFFF0000") // Rouge
                {
                    point.Visual.Fill = _oColorGreen;
                    oDay.m_sColor = "#FF2AFF00";
                }
                else if (sColor.ToUpper() == "#FF2AFF00") //Vert
                {
                    point.Visual.Fill = _oColorDefault;
                    oDay.m_sColor = "#FFFFFFFF";
                }
                else if (sColor.ToUpper() == "#FFFFFFFF") // blanc default
                {
                    point.Visual.Fill = _oColorRed;
                    oDay.m_sColor = "#FFFF0000";
                }
                else
                {
                    point.Visual.Fill = oSolidColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                oDay.m_sColor = "#FFA5A5A5";
            }

            iChart.Invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't respond to an answer by posting your comment as a new answer. Add a comment instead. If you need more space than a comment allows to clarify your problem edit your question instead.